# How to backup an Sql Server on the "Cloud"

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008

We are a small company and have the chance to move our Sql Server that we host in our office to the "Cloud". In this case the Cloud means the server would be running on a virtual machine at another Company. We would pay a monthly fee for this service. The service includes Sql Server 2008 pre-installed. We can access the server via Remote Desktop and have full control of the machine.

What would be the best way to backup the Sql databases and get the backups transferred to our office over the Internet? Is log shipping possible over the Internet?

Comment: How large is/are the database(s), how much traffic do they get and how current do you want to keep your local copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to have a maintenance plan doing a nightly backup to disk for a few days on rotation, and then a scheduled task script which uploads the latest backup to your site by SFTP/FTPS/HTTPS.

I believe log shipping with WAN links is possible as long as the link speed and reliability is up to the amount of traffic, but then you'd have to monitor the replication and keep a similarly specified SQL server at your office ... which kind of makes the whole move to the cloud a bit pointless, no?